# sign in sign out in a website using google plus

Tags: javascript, html

> I want to signin/signout in a wesite using google plus ,below is my code

```
<html>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="fsdfsdf.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<title>Login With google plus</title>    
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
        $('#signout').show();
    }
</script>
<a href="#" id="signout" onclick="signOut();" style="display: none;">Sign out</a>
<script>
    function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            console.log('User signed out.');
        });
    }
</script>
```

> But the problem is signin has working perfectly but when i try to signout it will not work,console message will show but not signout.

Comment: Is it signing out of your app? If yes, that is what it is supposed to do, to sign out of only your app not from the google in your browser. If want to set up for signing out of all application, need to delete the auth token.

Comment: yes i want to signout from web application ,so how i delete auth token?

Comment: try this: 

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/delete